# Let $M$ be a nonzero cyclic module. $M$ is simple iff $\mathrm{Ann}(M)$ is a maximal left ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm struggling a bit with the proof of this statement.

What I have is that, letting $M$ be a module over the ring $R$ (not necessarily commutative), $\exists \,x\in M$ s.t. $M=Rx$. Now, using the first isomorphism theorem, I get that $M\cong R/\mathrm{Ann}_R(x)$, and if I could prove that $\mathrm{Ann}_R(x) = \mathrm{Ann}_R(M)$, then since I know that $\mathrm{Ann}_R(x)$ is a maximal left ideal, I would be done.

But in order to prove that $\mathrm{Ann}_R(x) = \mathrm{Ann}_R(M)$, it seems that I would have to show for $r\in \mathrm{Ann}_R(x), s\in R$, that $rsx=0 \implies r\in\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)$, which seems false.

Comment: Are you sure this is right?  The annihilator of $M$ is a two-sided ideal.

Comment: The answer in the book assumes that $M\cong R/\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)$.

Comment: If $R$ is commutative, that should be right.  If not, you should just have $M \cong R/\textrm{ann}_R(x)$ for any $0 \neq x \in M$.

Comment: In the noncommutative case, would it be true then that $M\cong R/\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)$?

Comment: No. I've come across this in my research. A cyclic module over a noncommutative ring need not be isomorphic to the quotient by its annihilator.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is true.  Let $R$ be any ring with identity with maximal left ideal $\mathfrak M$ which is *not* a two sided ideal.  Let $M$ be the left $R$-module $R/\mathfrak M$.  Then $M$ is a simple left $R$-module.

Now, $\textrm{Ann}_R(M)$ is the set of $r \in R$ for which $rs \in \mathfrak M$ for all $s \in R$.  It is clearly a two-sided ideal.  Since $r \in \textrm{Ann}_R(M)$ implies $r1_R = r \in \mathfrak M$, we must have $\textrm{Ann}_R(M) \subseteq \mathfrak M$.  But this inclusion must be proper, because we chose $\mathfrak M$ to not be a two sided ideal.  Therefore, $\textrm{Ann}_R(M)$ is not maximal as a left ideal.